# Customizing toolbar items in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, toolbar, command, customization

Has the menu & toolbar customization functionality in VS2010 been reduced?

I can't seem to be able to select an icon for an added command, nor set it to be icon-only. Previous versions of Visual Studio supported this functionality and even allowed the creation/editing of custom icons.

Is this something that has suffered as a result of the move to the WPF-authored UI or am I missing something?

Comment: Another bit of missing functionality is not all buttons are available to be user-added to menus, even though they are already on some menus (compile item).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seems like this functionality was cut from Visual Studio 2010. This post has some info in the comments: [Customizing Visual Studio 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/visualstudio/archive/2009/12/14/customizing-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

Specifically - *"Unfortunately assigning or editing icons to commands through Customize dialog is not possible in VS2010. It is one of the features got cut for lack of time. This is however something we'll consider adding back in next version."*

The reply also has a longer explanation of a workaround.

Comment: Extremely helpful link. As explained there, the REASON for the reduced functionality is that they migrated the entire UI (shell and command system) from Win32 to one based solely on WPF. See my answer below for further details and updated developments.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2009/12/14/customizing-visual-studio-2010.aspx) mentioned in the answer from @Gordon Mackie JoanMiro, the REASON for the reduced functionality is that the VS Shell team migrated the entire UI (shell and command system) from Win32 to one based solely on WPF. This was a gargantuan task, I would imagine. However, a couple workarounds are now available:

1. You can export previously saved settings from VS 2008 and import them into VS 2010. That includes command bar customizations (as noted by @Don)
2. A [more recent blog-post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/06/17/command-image-changing-extension.aspx) contains detailed instructions for using a new extension to VS2010 (available on [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ff5060af-3df8-4063-b61b-19da41c66f20)) that allows users to change the images on the command UI. (Note that the old drag&drop customization interface is still not supported in this new extension.)

Answer (score 2):

If you have custom icons, any attempt to make ANY changes to the tool bar will result in the custom icons disappearing and being replaced by text when you restart VS2010.

The only way I found to get my custom icons without text into VS2010 is to open VS2008, set up all of the tool bars the way I want, including custom icons, then export the settings (Tools| Import and Export Settings).  Then open VS2010 and import those settings.  Tedious, I know, but it allows me to have a down arrow icon that searches for the next instance of the word my cursor is on.

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to customize VS2010 toolbars/keyboard and what took a few minutes in previous versions takes hours now.  The new system looks real pretty but is useless in practice.  Apart from the fact you just can't do (like change the appearance of buttons as mentioned above) the things you can do are extremely time-consuming and annoying.

Why is it every new version of VS loses something really useful?  Other examples:

1. VC++5 introduced a new HTML help system.  Pressing F1 on a function name used to immediately show help for that function.  After VC++5 getting context help became annoyingly much slower, and is still very slow (and inaccurate).
2. VS.Net (aka VS2002 or VC++7) had a useless bookmark system compared to VC++6.  VS2010 bookmarks are better but not perfect.
3. VS.Net removed the search state buttons "whole word", "case sensitive" etc.  These were possibly the most useful buttons ever as they quickly allowed you to see why a search may have failed.

Answer (score 1):

I found a great extension: [CommandingImage](http://i4.visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ff5060af-3df8-4063-b61b-19da41c66f20)

It does not have an icon editor, but you can create your images as 16x16 png format (for transparency) and import it (I recommend Paint.Net)

Answer (score -3):

Dave, here's how to add toolbar buttons:
1) in the IDE, find the down arrow looking thing on the far right of a toolbar and click on Add Remove Buttons, Customize
2) in the Customize window select the Menu Bar radio button then select the appropriate menu bar that you want to add a button to
3) click the "Add Command..." button
4) select the appropriate Category and Command button that you want to add, then click OK.

The command button you selected will be added to the menu bar you selected.  You can move the button up or down.

I think this is what you are looking for.

Good luck!

Comment: From his question, he already knows about that part.  He was asking why we can no longer select to be icon-only, and cannot change icons, (and other reduced functionality)